# React Native Redux state not getting updated by reducer function through slice?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Hi I am using react redux with toolkit and I am wondering why my state is not getting updated despite dispatching the action with the right payload. I am trying to update the user state in redux from null to an object containing the user data when they are logged in and vice versa. Am I correctly updating the state in an 'immutable' way in this case? Thanks for any help in advance.

UPDATE: It seems that it works when i change the initialState to an object refer to @aboutcoding answer. However my use case requires it to be null initially. I tried making state = 1 in my reducer function just to test whether it will update but it also doesn't. I am not sure why just equating state to a new value doesn't work since null is considered primitive which is immutable by default.

Here is the slice.js code:

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: null,
  reducers: {
    updateUser: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {updateUser} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Here is my store.js code:

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: null,
  reducers: {
    updateUser: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {updateUser} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

App.js where the action is disptached:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import LoginStack from './src/navigation/loginStack';
import DrawerNavigator from './src/navigation/drawer';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {updateUser} from './src/redux/userSlice';

export default function App() {
  // Set an initializing state while Firebase connects
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // Handle user state change
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    if (user) {
      const userData = {
        displayName: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
        emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
      };
      dispatch(updateUser(userData));
    } else {
      dispatch(updateUser(user));
    }

    if (initializing) {
      setInitializing(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber;
  });

  if (initializing) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      {!user ? (
        <>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <LoginStack />
          </NavigationContainer>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <DrawerNavigator />
          </NavigationContainer>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

My react dev tools shows that state did not changed after dispatching the action:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
{...action.payload}
```

As I always initialising my state I'm not sure you need to do it too. So try this below:

Update:

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

initialstate = {
  displayName: "",
  email: "",
  emailVerified: ""
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateUser: (state, action) => {
      state = {...action.payload};
    },
  },
});

export const {updateUser} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

You could also try to update your React DevTools. It seem to be out of the date. Maybe it's not working properly.

Comment: It still doesn't update it sadly the dev tools still shows the same output :( It's similar to the one suggested by @Jignesh

Comment: See Update above

Comment: I tried but the the state still remains the same even after updating dev tools. Just that now is an object without with empty strings on each property. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Then try this: Object.assign(state, action.payload)

Comment: It updates! May i know why the spread operator wasn't working in this case?

Comment: Well the state is immutable so spread operator is not working. Maybe it could work if you spread the state too like this: { ...state, ...action.payload }. Object.assign does a shallow copy so it seems to work for immutable objects. Maybe you can upvote this answer :)

Comment: I see although it works when i make the initialState an object. I need it to be null or an object vice versa and I tried doing state = 1 to test whether it will update but it doesn't (still initial value null). I thought that primitives are immutable in javascript and so I wonder why it doesnt work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the below method.

Like:

```
updateUser: (state, action) => {
  state = {
      ...action.payload
  }
},
```

Mutating the state will not reflect the changes at render-cycle.

Comment: It still doesn't update it sadly the dev tools still shows the same output